# Do I need to explicitly close the StreamReader in C# when using it to load a file into a string variable?

Tags: c#, streamreader

Example:

```
variable = new StreamReader( file ).ReadToEnd();
```

Is that acceptable?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No, this will not close the StreamReader.  You need to close it.  Using does this for you (and disposes it so it's GC'd sooner):

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
  allFileText = r.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Or alternatively in .Net 2 you can use the new File. static members, then you don't need to close anything:

```
variable = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
```

Comment: `ReadAllText` was added in .Net 2.0 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=VS.80).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Jared (edited answer).  TBH I only came across it recently.  Once you know one way you generally tend to stick with what works.

Comment: Is there a perfomance difference when using StreamReader.ReadToEnd vs File.ReadAllTest?

Answer (score 22):

You should always dispose of your resources.

```
// the using statement automatically disposes the streamreader because
// it implements the IDisposable interface
using( var reader = new StreamReader(file) )
{
    variable = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Or at least calling it manually:

```
reader = new StreamReader(file);
variable = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

Comment: For someone who doesn't know that the using statement automatically takes care of this for you, this would be confusing.  No down vote, but no up vote either because this is just not worded for a beginner to understand.

Comment: Added a comment to be helpful

Comment: In your second example you don't call *Dispose()* at all. And there is no *try-catch* mechanism to make sure that *Close()* is called. When you add both, a *try-catch* and a *Dispose()* call it will result in nothing else than a *using*, like in your first example.

Comment: This explains it well however it doesn't mention, as badbod99 and a couple others did, "Or alternatively in .Net 4 you can use the new File. static members, then you don't need to close anything"

Answer (score 7):

You need to Dispose of objects that implement `IDisposable`. Use a `using` statement to make sure it gets disposed without explicitly calling the Dispose method.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
  variable = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Alternately, use [`File.ReadAllText(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

```
variable = File.ReadAllText(file);
```

Comment: +1 but I'd word it "you don't need to explicitly close it if you use a "using" statement to make sure it gets disposed. +1 because this is more clearly worded than Dismissile's answer. His answer does nothing to explain that the using statement will dispose of the resources for you, and someone who didn't know that would be left scratching their head.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, whenever you create a disposable object you must dispose of it preferably with a using statement

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file)) {
  variable = reader.ReadToEnd(file);
}
```

In this case though you can just use the `File.ReadAllText` method to simplify the expression

```
variable = File.ReadAllText(file);
```

Comment: This was helpful though badbod99 supplied a few more specifics. I'm assuming those specifics are correct as I"m only just getting into code outside of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to close `StreamReader`. Use the following template:

```
string contents;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file)) 
{
   contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using the **using** keyword; then you don't need to explicitly close anything.