# In C# VS2013 how do you read a resource txt file one line at a time?

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0

```
             static void Starter(ref int[,] grid)
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(Resources.Sudoku));
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();

                    Console.Write(line);
                    Console.ReadLine();           
                }
```

I know this isn't right, but it gets my point across. 
I would like to be able to read in the resource file one line at a time.
Like so:

```
                    System.IO.StreamReader StringFromTxt 
                        = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
             string line = StringFromTxt.ReadLine();
```

I do not necessarily have to read in from the resource, but I am not sure of any other way to call a text file without knowing the directory every time, or hard coding it. I can't have the user pick files.

Answer (score 2):

`StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:\\CountryCodew.txt");
     while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
    }`

Comment: Don't forget to close. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136490/do-i-need-to-explicitly-close-the-streamreader-in-c-sharp-when-using-it-to-load

Comment: Even beter: use a using!

Answer (score 0):

MSDN lists the following as the way to read in one line at a time:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx

```
int counter = 0;  //keep track of #lines read
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine (line);
   counter++;
}

file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

Additional examples for getline:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2whx1zkx.aspx