# How to read a multiline string from a file using StreamReader?

Tags: c#, streamreader

Given this text data from a file:

```
Mehmet;Demirayak;IT
1
Emre;Araz;Sekten Chef
1
Nusret;Beganovic;Kein Geld
2
Ferhat;Acer;Acer Computer
2
Fevzi;Uzun;Trabzon
```

my goal is to read it using a StreamReader and store it in my defined class Personen.

If I had to split only one argument, it's not a problem. In other words, if the text in the file would be written only with the separator ";" and without any space or new line characters, I'd know how to read it. However, when I get a more complex structure in my data, such the one above, I am not sure how to read it.

This is why I have tried so far:

```
public void read()
{
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(datei);
   string s;
   int i = 0;

    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
          string[] l = s.Split(";");
      if(s.StartsWith("1") || s.StartsWith("2"))
      {
          p[i] = new Personen(l[0], l[1], l[2]);
          Console.WriteLine(p[i]);
          i++;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: seems like you just want to loop over `l` and check `StartsWith` on each item in the array but it's not entirely clear since none of your segments tarts with `1` or `2`.

Comment: Or does one line contain multiple "objects", each with 3 string segments?

Comment: Can you change that "data format"? Either use a _decent_ CSV format or maybe consider json.

Comment: Does the digit "1" or "2" apply to the next line or the previous line? Note that it is not on the same line as the data is belongs to.

Comment: the problem is that my teacher dont allow us to work with json. the object has 3 string segments. the digit 1 and 2 is just there without a specific function, its only to learn there. we should read from the beginning mehmet go on, and at the digit 1 we should jump to the next text data that starts with Emre. i use the Start.With because i dont know how to read this text data, and if i work with the split, i can only split for ";" or for the digits, but i need both.

Comment: @SuperBabaMo It sounds like you need to read a line, and if it is "1" or "2" then you read the next line and split it. If the split gives 3 parts then you add that to `p`.

Comment: yes thats what the code should to do. it read a line, if the 1 or 2 cames then it jumps to the next line, so i was thinking about to work with the starts.with because i dont know nothing another to spell the programm to go on to read

Comment: Use two ReadLine() method calls inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion in the comments under your question, in order to achieve your goal you can use the following logic for each line you read. If you indeed read '1' or '2', then skip the split operation for the current line and jump one iteration ahead by using `continue` (thanks @PeterB for [pointing out my mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77489742/c-sharp-streamreader/77491295#comment136613465_77491295) in the original answer). If not, then proceed to split the current line and store it into `p`:

```
public static void Read(Stream stream)
{
    using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    string s;
    int i = 0;

    while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        var lineStartsWithControlDigit = s[0] == '1' || s[0] == '2';

        if (lineStartsWithControlDigit)
        {
            continue;
        }

        string[] l = s.Split(";");
        p[i] = new Personen(l[0], l[1], l[2]);
        
        Console.WriteLine(p[i]);
        
        i++;
    }
}
```

Also note that your statement `Console.WriteLine(p[i])` is going to print only `"Personen"` which is not so meaningful. In order for it to print nicely the contents of the Personen object in `p[i]`, you can override the method `ToString()` in `class Personen`:

```
public class Personen
{
    string FirstPerson { get; set; }
    string SecondPerson { get; set; }
    string ThirdPerson { get; set; }

    public Personen(string firstPerson, string secondPerson, string thirdPerson)
    {
        FirstPerson = firstPerson;
        SecondPerson = secondPerson;
        ThirdPerson = thirdPerson;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{FirstPerson};{SecondPerson};{ThirdPerson}";
    }
}
```

Running the program and calling `read()` produces the following output in the console:

```
Mehmet;Demirayak;IT
Emre;Araz;Sekten Chef
Nusret;Beganovic;Kein Geld
Ferhat;Acer;Acer Computer
Fevzi;Uzun;Trabzon
```

It's important to close the stream once you are done working with it, that's why I also added `using` in front of the instantiation of `StreamReader sr`. See more about this at [Do I need to explicitly close the StreamReader in C# when using it to load a file into a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136490/do-i-need-to-explicitly-close-the-streamreader-in-c-sharp-when-using-it-to-load).

Comment: If I read this correctly, it needs the file to start with a "control digit line", but it doesn't.

Comment: @PeterB Thanks for your correction, you are right and indeed the first line is missing from the output. I'll try to fix it. I've also noted, after writing the whole answer, that the original post presented a single line input, but for some reason it has been edited and changed to a multiline string.

Comment: The original source already had line breaks, but no formatting to make them show correctly. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/036c5ba3-bd55-46eb-8038-aa31381c8f20/view-source

Comment: @PeterB I see, I understand it now, thank you! I've also fixed my reply and it should take into account that the first line doesn't start with a "control digit"

Comment: Add a if `(i % 2==0) { Your code }`

Comment: @Magnus I don't understand, can you explain where and why add ```if (i % 2==0) { Your code }```?

Comment: Read every 2nd row